# Text links wont style and are not always clickable

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I've got a mess with two links at the top of this page ("WORK" and "ABOUT").

http://danux.me/

I'm not sure why I can't get them to style. I only seem to be able to apply a float and nothing else in the CSS does anything.

```
#nav_container {

float: right;
position: relative;
padding-right: 110px;
padding-top: 60px; 
}




#nav_container li {
float: left;  
display: inline;
color: #fff;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

As far as the clickable part, if I expand my browser so they are off to the right of the tiled images they are clickable.

I have the tiled images set to relative for that overlap effect, and the blue bar is set to absolute.

I have the z-index higher for the tiled images and tried applying a higher z-index to those nav links thinking I could get them to pop up on top and be clickable, but no dice.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `#home_console_wrapper` element actually overlaps your `#color_beam`, and has a large `padding-top` on it to hide this behaviour. It also has a higher `z-index`, meaning that it will make your links unclickable.

To rectify this, you need to remove `position: absolute` from `#color_beam`, and `padding-top: 190px` from `#home_console_wrapper`.

This will cause your links to become clickable, without changing the display at all.

If you would like to still have the slight 'overlap' effect, simply set a negative `margin-top` on `#home_console_wrapper`:

```
#home_console_wrapper {
  margin-top: -35px;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I came to the right place! Thanks Obsidian! Ill try it tomorrow! (and that all makes sense.)

Comment: Ah! I couldn't help myself. I did it now and it works! Love that idea of the negative margin!.